# HBase supports random reads but HDFS is good at batch reads

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

Correct me if I am wrong with my concepts. HBase is built on top of HDFS. HBase is good at random reads whereas HDFS is built for batch processing. Can someone tell me how this happens?

I am sure the guys behind the architecture of HBase did some wonder. I can't understand how though. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I would take a look at [HBase: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920014348.do)

Comment: duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248903/how-does-hbase-enable-random-access-to-hdfs